# What logs would be written if file system is full in UNIX?

Tags: filesystems, logs, monitoring, disk-usage, aix

I am working on a unix server and I guess during some time in past the file system had been full. However, I need some solid data to prove it. Will there be any OS logs or something of that sort to confirm my assumption?

It's an AIX system.

Comment: Which flavour of UNIX? Depending on the flavour, you may or may not have some evidence of the issue in /var/log, /var/adm/, errpt, syslog, or some other locations.

Comment: If the filesystem is where the logs are stored is full, where would it log the condition?

Comment: An easy way to test would be to create a VM with the minimum amount of space to install and just create a file via `dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1024  count=FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES` to fill up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On AIX, you will get entries in the standard error log if a filesystem operation fails due to a filesystem being full.  You can view that error log with the `errpt` command.

You will see something like this,

```
IDENTIFIER TIMESTAMP T C RESOURCE_NAME DESCRIPTION
xxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxx I O SYSJ2         UNABLE TO ALLOCATE SPACE IN FILE SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect without proof that there is a log entry sent to the console when a disk-full condition occurs. If so, `alog -o -t console` should show it to you. It should be easy to experiment: fill up a disk (on a non-production system!) and see what appears in `alog`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree with EightBitTony with his answer. For a detailed description about which exact filesystem was full, you could go ahead with the following commands:

errpt | grep -i "unable to allocate to allocate space in filesystem"
errpt -aj *identifier-code*
df -gt *mount-point*

You could also pinpoint the exact date and time for it in the first command itself where you will know it from the timestamp given.